# Spring oauth2. Default scheme for turning a authorization_code into acces_token

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

How the following scheme is implemented in spring:

- after a request to the resource server, comes the authorization_code
- it comes to redirect_uri
- **further, somewhere in the spring, the authorization_code is processed. Most likely another request is made to the resource server, along with this code. Then comes the access_token, which is placed in the session.**

With my resource server, spring does not behave correctly. I need to write my own code for processing a request by redirect_url.

How can I do it?

config file

```yaml
        registration:
          vk:
            client-id: xxx
            client-secret: xxx
            redirect_uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/callback/vk
            scope: notify,friends,photos,wall,ads,groups,stats,email
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code

        provider:
          vk:
            authorization-uri: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize
            token-uri: https://oauth.vk.com/access_token
            user-info-uri: https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?fields=screen_name,email
            user-name-attribute: response.screen_name
```

code that works fine until the stage of getting the code by redirect url

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/public").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login/oauth2/callback/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

if you add the following point, then it will get the correct authorization_code

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login/oauth2/callback/vk")
    public @ResponseBody void generateReport(
            @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
            @RequestParam(value = "state", required = false) String state,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Requests for authorization code and then tokens are sent to **authorization** server (not resource server). This has nothing specific to Spring, this is just how OAuth2 authorization_code flow is specified (and this is why you have to provide both authorization and token URIs in application properties).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I most likely state my thoughts with errors.
By and large, I want to add my handler in the code. This handler should receive the authorization_code that comes at the redirect_url and turn the code into a token (by requesting the authorization server)

It is desirable that this scheme be as standard as possible, so that I change a minimum of default settings. Therefore, I want to know where exactly in spring security a request is processed that comes from the redirect_url

Comment: Then you open the manual and go to advanced configuration. But considering your mastery of OAuth2 standard and Spring framework, you'll most likely introduce security breaches.

Comment: I have already re-read this section 5 times. I have about 300 commented lines in this config, with various customization options. I tried to change behavior: accessTokenResponseClient, authorizationRequestResolver, authorizationRequestResolver, userAuthoritiesMapper, oidcUserService.
I just returned null and looked through the breakpoint what comes to me in the method arguments. And nowhere did I come across the authorization_code.

The only place I can get it is at the point I showed above.

Maybe you know which of these settings is responsible for what I want to do?